# When doing Ajna meditation, what should I visualize?

Tags: meditation, chakras

I am currently trying to do meditation, focusing on opening (awakening) my Ajna (third eye) chakra.

I already imagine a candle flame slightly moving when I breath in and when I breath out, it moves faster.

### What should I visualize?

Should I visualize a candle or even a purple (or indigo) aura ball?

By the way, should I meditate before sleeping (at night)? I've read somewhere when it says that the third eye awakens more in complete darkness.